# An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation -mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

I use two model in a single view so for that i make a class in i which I put both model.But when i use it, it gives me error.

Model:

```
namespace Laboratory_Management.Models
{
    public class PatientandTest
    {
        public PatientTbl PatientTbl { get; set; }
        public PatientTestTbl PatientTestTbl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Laboratory_Management.Models.PatientandTest

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index1";
}

<h1>Index1</h1>

<h4>PatientTbl</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Index1" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PatientTbl.PName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PatientTbl.PName" class="form-control" id="PName" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PatientTbl.PName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
         </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you get the error?I tried as you mentioned and it worked well,If you don't spcific the type of the page ,you may get the error when you try with the tag helper asp-for,but since you've spcificed the type with @model,it should be OK

Comment: When i use asp-for = "PatientTbl.TestName" then here it gives the error of dynamic opertaion

Comment: Could you show more codes related so that we could reproduce the error?